# Best Way to make Service using location data

Tags: java, android, location, android-service, android-location

I'm creating an Android application, that makes some logging tags, while user is moving.

I decided to create three Service.
The First service is managing log in internet, geting commands to get location and to write location.

The Second service is managing location data: transforming raw location data from google api ( make some approximation and calculation ), putting it into nolockingqueque and giving last sample from it.

The Third service is something like this: https://gist.github.com/blackcj/20efe2ac885c7297a676 . Service, which is getting raw location data and raising broadcast, that location data had been updated.

Broadcast reciever Binds to the Second service, gives him location data.

I'm filling that this way is too hard and it is not the best. 
In fact I need three things in application:
some container with computedLocationInformation
Thread or service which will get Raw Location Data from Google Services
Service which will use computedLocationInformation.

Can you give me better architecture for this issue, please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done within a single service. You can create three different thread in the single service and all three thread will do their own job but its all depends on your logic how you will manage all these operations

Comment: I thought about it, but I don't know, how to create thread, which will be triggered by google api'es location callbacks.